# Launcher icons on desktop or in the main panel

Tags: 11.10, launcher, gnome-panel, icons

Is there any way to simply add launcher icons such as firefox, gimp, etc. onto the desktop or into the gnome panel ?

I know that possible way how to do that is to run this command:

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new /home/profile/Desktop
```

but it's too slowly and annoying writing this command whenever you want to add some icon...

Thanks.

I use Ubuntu 11.10 - Gnome shell

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to right-click your desktop at all? Are there icons? Two things to try:

#### gnome-tweak-tool

This app might also show up as Advanced Settings if you have it installed already. Otherwise:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Run it and go to `Desktop`. Check `Have file manager handle the desktop` to the ON position.

#### dconf-editor

Install dconf-tools, which includes this tool:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Run it and navigate to this position:

```
org > gnome > desktop > background
```

Check `show-desktop-icons` to on.